# When and why use subscribe's error handler?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've noticed that even if I don't include the error handler in my subscribe call back, my error will still get logged to the console. It seems like Angular logs all errors to the console by default, am I right in this assumption?

For example if I include the error handler:

```
  console.log("beep");

  of(1,2,3,4).pipe(
    mergeMap(data => {
      if (data === 3) {
      return throwError('Error Occurred for data: '+ 3);
      }
      return of(data);
    })
    ).subscribe(res => console.log(res),
     err => console.error(err)
    );

   console.log("bop");
```

The output in my browser console is

```
beep
1
2
Error Occurred for data: 3
bop
```

Now if I take out the error handler in my subscribe, like so

```
console.log("beep");

  of(1,2,3,4).pipe(
    mergeMap(data => {
      if (data === 3) {
      return throwError('Error Occurred for data: '+ 3);
      }
      return of(data);
    })
    ).subscribe(res => console.log(res)
    );

   console.log("bop");
```

I get this in my console:

```
Beep
1
2
Bop
ERROR Error Occurred for data: 3
```

What's causing this discrepancy? I know throwError returns an Observable that emits an error notification, and errorHandler (ends the stream lifecycle?) and receives the error. So if I take out the errorHandler, is the throwError Observable being treated like a value by the success handler function?

And in general I feel like it's unnecessary to do any type of error handling for things like http and stuff, cause even if I leave the error handler off my subscribe callback, angular seems to take care of errors for me by logging 404 not found messages and such to the console.

Comment: You add the handler so that you can cleanly handle any errors in a way that works best for your app. It's like a try/catch for a service. If you run JS that throws an error without catching it, you'll see it in the console. This is similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do when you hit an HTTP error is log an error message to the console then you don’t need to subscribe to the error handler.  You should not subscribe to error handlers (or catch exceptions) unless you can handle them in some way.

Sometimes however you might want to do something different.  Maybe there is a backup server you can try.  Maybe you want to redirect the user to a different error page.  Maybe you can just disable one part of the site and everything else can keep working.  Maybe the error means the server is busy and you should retry in 30 seconds.

In these cases you would want to subscribe to that error handler and take action.  Although, even then, you might use a `catch` operator or some other mechanism.